# Part::pkspec1: The expression j cannot be used as a part specification

Tags: symbolic, list-manipulation

I want to do some stuff with symbolic arrays like this

```
a[[j]] + a[[j + 1]] == a[[j - 1]] + a[[j - 2]]
```

But upon declaring such an expression I get

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression j cannot be used as a part specification.
```

for all indices in the expression. It also does not work with the above expression when, for example, putting it into solve.

How can I do symbolic math with smybolic arrays?

EDIT:
Example

```
Solve[a[[j]] + a[[j + 1]] == a[[j - 1]] + a[[j - 2]], a[[j]]]
```

Comment: I don't want to do recursive stuff

Comment: Use `Indexed[]`.

Comment: Use Solve[a[j] + a[j + 1] == a[j - 1] + a[j - 2], a[j]], which solves for a[j].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably really want to use `a[j]` and `RSolve[]` instead. The code

```
RSolve[a[j] + a[1 + j] == a[-2 + j] + a[-1 + j], a[j], j]
```

returns

```
{{a[j] -> (-1)^j*C[1] + (-1)^j*j*C[2] + C[3]}}
```

But you may still want to do it your way. The code

```
Solve[ a[j] + a[j + 1] == a[j - 1] + a[j - 2], a[j]]
```

returns

```
{{a[j] -> a[-2 + j] + a[-1 + j] - a[1 + j]}}
```

which may be what you want. A third alternative mentioned in comments is to use
`Indexed[a,j]` instead of `a[[j]]`. The function `Indexed[]` was introduced
in 2014 with version 10.0 of Mathematica.

Comment: I had used this Notation before but I did not like the "wrong" semantics since single parantheses are for function calls but if does not work otherwise….

Comment: Keep in mind that Mathematica does not have "functions" as in other computer languages.It has pattern matching, rewrite rules, evaluation rules, and symbolic expressions. You may think that `f[x] = x^2` defines a "squaring function" but it doesn't. Even `f[x_] := x^2` which is the closest equivalent is not a function.