# Implementing While loop in module that will iterate correctly

Tags: recursion, iteration

I am attempting to write a module that prints an optimal path from a starting node to a destination node. The first node is 1 and the final node is 100 (though when module prints these they should be 0 and 99 respectively). The module takes as inputs a distance matrix, Q, and a list, J, whose elements are the shortest-path weight from node i to destination node. Below is my best attempt.

```
findPathandTotalCost3[Q_, J_] := Module[
  {costs, node, v, w, i},
  i = 1;
  costs[i_] := 
   costs[i] = Table[Q[[node[i], w]] + J[[w]], {w, Length[J]}];
  node[1] = 1;
  node[2] = Position[costs[1], Min[costs[1]]];
  node[i] = Position[costs[i - 1], Min[costs[i - 1]];
    While[node[i] < 100,
     (Print[node[i] - 1]; ++i; costs[i]; node[i];)];];]
```

All my attempts at implementing this module seem to have problems with either correctly iterating or specifying which parts are recursive. Below is a typical error output.

```
findPathandTotalCost3[Q, J]

Part::pkspec1: The expression node$45807[0] cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression node$45807[0] cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression node$45807[0] cannot be used as a part specification.

General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

0
```

As can be seen, the first node prints correctly ("0") but the module subsequently doesn't evaluate properly.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to make this work? I can post more of my code attempts if helpful. Thanks

EDIT: Q and J below. Q is too large to paste in full, but is a list of 100 lists, each similar to:

```
{Infinity, 0.04, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 11.11, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 72.21, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 
  Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 
  Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 
  Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 
  Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}, 
 {Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 20.59, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 64.94, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 
  Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 
  Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 1247.25, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 
  Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 
  Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}
```

where, e.g. 0.04 is the edgeweight 1->2.

J:

```
{160.55, 162.26, 88.52, 143.73, 145.12, 147.43, 141.67, 144.1, \
149.44, 140.95, 150.8, 141.99, 148.93, 303.77, 130.85, 107.01, \
128.15, 114.66, 104.44, 124.66, 124.42, 168.62, 200.27, 88.21, \
114.61, 102.74, 112.81, 112.8, 131.97, 70.38, 71.45, 176.51, 66.16, \
65.84, 110.18, 64.7, 156.07, 67.8, 67.44, 63.95, 77.15, 62.61, 58.66, \
149.25, 50.72, 52.26, 67.53, 48.58, 65.21, 46.27, 45.76, 54.36, \
135.03, 44.38, 54.99, 42.16, 40.05, 40.03, 62.47, 30.69, 33.02, 37.5, \
35.56, 38.77, 32.62, 34.98, 34.34, 31.39, 31.68, 30.47, 30.41, 30.02, \
35.96, 22.04, 21.16, 21.45, 20.64, 42.31, 79.71, 8.91, 33.37, 77.12, \
15.27, 10.37, 33.5, 7.46, 85.72, 4.8, 4.59, 37.6, 13.56, 22.8, 11.87, \
3.28, 3.09, 0.27, 1.06, 0.63, 0.33, 0}
```

Comment: Hi, on my machine with `V13` I have not been able to reproduce your errors. I am attaching a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L7FT.png) so you can check for yourself

Comment: How do you expect someone to run your code if they do not have access to `Q` and `J` ? But see [partpkspec1-the-expression-j-cannot-be-used-as-a-part-specification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193443/partpkspec1-the-expression-j-cannot-be-used-as-a-part-specification)

Comment: @bmf  you need Q and J to run the code.

Comment: Hi @Nasser I have added J and (some of) Q

Comment: You could make a Minimal input?  The error you see is not related to how large J and Q are. And it is better to paste the input using InputForm to make it easier to copy.

Comment: @Nasser yes, I kind of figured that. I was trying to be polite :)

Comment: @Nasser I've changed Q and J to input form. I wasn't meaning my code wasn't working because of Q's size, but it exceeded the character length for my Question.

Comment: You are calling `Position[costs[i - 1], Min[costs[i - 1]]];`  but when `i=1` then `i-1` is zero. Right? Then in `costs` the input `i` is therefore zero. Then inside `costs` function you use `Q[[node[i],w]]` to index into `Q`.  But you can not use `node[0]` as Part specifications as it is not defined and has no value. You seem to have the `index one off` bug which is very common in programming.

Comment: @nasser I've defined node[0]=1 now, but my code still isn't working. This is the output error now: findPathandTotalCost3[Q, J]

Part::pkspec1: The expression node$4668[-1+i$4668] cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression node$4668[-1+i$4668] cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression node$4668[-1+i$4668] cannot be used as a part specification.

General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the semantics of J are (I haven't reverse-engineered the code), but if it's just an adjustment to the weights, then it could be applied first. But setting that aside, why not just use the built in FindShortestPath function? You can create a graph from your weighted adjacency matrix and plug it into FindShortestPath with your desired start/end nodes.

Comment: @lericr Q is a 100x100 matrix, with entry {i,j} representing the edge weight from node i to node j. J is a list of costs/weights of the path from a node i to the destination node, 100. I have tried adding J to Q as you have suggested, but still encounter the same Part::pkspec error I mentioned to Nasser

Comment: Okay, so J is sort of a weighting/scaling factor for any path between two nodes (well, it sounds like between any node and the specific node 100). So, if we're fixing the terminal node to be 100, then the entire matrix Q could be multiplied by whatever entry in J corresponds to our initial node. So, that part seems easy, but more to the point, it means that you already have all of the machinery you need to use the built in Graph-related functions.

Answer (score 1):

For explicitness, I'll generate some fake data and then use the built-in functions.

```
weightedAdjacencyMatrix =
  With[
    {maxWeightCount = 15, nodeCount = 10, maxWeight = 20},
    With[
      {edgeCoordinates = 
        DeleteCases[
          RandomInteger[{1, nodeCount}, {maxWeightCount, 2}], {a_, a_}]},
      SparseArray[
        MapThread[
          Rule, 
          {edgeCoordinates, 
           RandomReal[{0, maxWeight}, 
             Length@edgeCoordinates]}], 
        {nodeCount, nodeCount}, 
        Infinity]]]
```

We can create a Graph directly from this.

```
graph = 
  WeightedAdjacencyGraph[weightedAdjacencyMatrix, 
    VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

The options aren't necessary, but can be useful later to understand verify the results.

The following will give you the shortest path (using the edge weights).

```
FindShortestPath[graph, 1, 10]
```

And the next will give you the distance.

```
GraphDistance[graph, 1, 10]
```

Does that answer your question? Obviously I chose a small graph for clarity/experimentation, but could this be applied to your situation? I've left out how to mulitply the path weightings (contained in J) to the edge weightings (contained in Q).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Sorry I forgot to mention in my last response to you that this is a school assignment and therefore I have to build a FindShortestPath module myself. I'll paste the instruction below. "Write a module findPathAndTotalCost that takes a distance matrix, Q and
a cost-to-go function J and uses them to find the optimal (cheapest) path from start
to end and its cost. Test your code on the data in the graph.txt file by showing the
optimal path and finding its minimum cost. Hint: Your findPathAndTotalCost should
of course make use of the findCostToGo module".

Comment: Oh! Sorry! Looking back I should have realized this.

Comment: Are you required to use an imperative/While-loop approach? I would have started thinking about NestWhile or FixedPoint.

Comment: no, the only requirement is that it's in a module and calls Q, J, and uses the cost-to-go module which I have already written. What I included in the previous comment is all the requirements stipulated